# Alternative to Rails with Asset Pipeline

Tags: web-applications, asset-pipeline, assets, singlepage

I'm writing a single page web app using Rails.
I don't really use Rails at all and it's quite slow at compiling assets (which is the only thing I use rails for) so I want something faster.

I'm open to most frameworks as long as they run on Heroku.

What I really need is Coffeescript support as well as hamlc support (https://github.com/netzpirat/haml-coffee).

I'm also using SASS today but I'm open to switch to something else as long as the syntax is similar.

The most important feature of Rails is packaging assets and that I don't have to restart the webserver to see changes.

It's an absolute requirement that a cachebuster is appended to the asset filename and that the assets are concatenated.

So, ideas? I guess node.js would be a strong argument but has anyone made a good asset pipeline for node?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Serve](http://get-serve.com)? I'm writing a site using it right now and so far has been really helpful. It's lighter than Rails while offering support for things like partials, offers support for ERB, SASS and CoffeeScript (with the rack-coffee gem) and runs on any Rack-enabled service provider, such as Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

You also might want to look at [connect-assets](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets). It allows you to work with unminified assets in development and then takes care of the minification based on a environment variable for production.